# Rails unit testing failing due to Devise admin user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a simple unit test:

```
def test_conversation_without_a_name_is_invalid
    conversation = Conversation.new
    assert conversation.name.blank?
    assert !conversation.valid?
end
```

that is failing with:

> 1) Error:
>   test_conversation_without_a_name_is_invalid(ConversationTest):
>   ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: PG::Error: ERROR:  duplicate key value
>   violates unique constraint "index_admins_on_email" DETAIL:  Key
>   (email)=() already exists.

It seems that for some reason the test is trying to create a Devise admin user and failing, but I have no idea why it is trying to do this in the first place, or even how to correct it.

I ran the same test in the rails console and it worked fine, very confused.

Has anyone run into this before or know what is going on?  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Some things to try: 1. run `rake db:test:prepare` to cleanup your testing database. 2. make sure you're not creating an admin on a `setup` block on this test. 3. make sure you are not using a fixture that creates an admin

Comment: Alfonso, great suggestions.  No sense cleaning up the db since it gets re-created, but your 3rd suggestion had me check the test_helper.rb and there it was:   fixtures :all was set.  After removing, it works fine!

Comment: I found that clearing the user fixtures generated by Devise fixed everything

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tracked it down to a `fixtures:all` statement in my test_helper.rb, still learning my way in Rails, but thanks to Alfonso for the great suggetions.

Comment: I had a similar problem, but in my case populating the Admin fixture values solve the problem.  I was seeing the error because Devise created two fixtures but didn't set values on either so the unique constraint was violated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that inside `admins.yml` and `users.yml` there are two "identical" empty objects "{}" and it throws `Key (email)=() already exists` error while creating the second one.
deleting `fixtures:all` will stop the loading of all the fixtures, instead delete or comment the second object

```
one: {}
# column: value
#
# two: {}
# column: value
#
```